# On the definition of the number $i$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, definition

$i$ is defined as a root of the polynomial $x^2+1$. However, both $i$ and $-i$ obey this definition.

So, basically, there should be no way to distinguish the two (in the sense that replacing $i$ and $-i$ everywhere would yield the exact same results), right? But, operators such as $\Im$ (imaginary part) do let us distinguish between the two!
How do we define the action of $\Im$ as well-defined?

Also, does this mean that the theory of complex numbers relies on the fact that we can distinguish between the roots?
Trying to make sense of this makes me a bit confused, but I believe there is a simple explanation.

Secondly, does the definition assume that there are only $2$ complex roots to $x^2+1$? I'm having a hard time understanding "what comes before what", the fundamental theorem of algebra, the definition of $i$, the theory of complex numbers...?

This is the first time I've thought of the fact that $i$ is not uniquely defined.

I would love for a clear explanation. Thank you.

Comment: But are $\pm 1$ _defined_ as the roots of $x^2-1$?

Comment: You are correct that they are replaceable. We pick one of the two roots, and call it $i.$ It doesn't matter which one. If you want to accent the symmetry, you can add the roots $i,j$ with $i^2=j^2=-1$ and $i+j=0.$ We don't know which is which root, and it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is a very perceptive question. Usually when you first treat the complex numbers rigorously, this is resolved by just defining $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$ and (arbitrarily) defining $i = (0, 1)$. You're right that choosing $i = (0, -1)$ would also work, and you're also right that just declaring "let $i$ be a root of $x^2 + 1$" is an incomplete definition. However in the subject of Galois Theory, it does turn out that you can do things like that ("taking the splitting field"), and that there is some arbitrariness (this is quantified by "the Galois Group of the splitting field").

Comment: $i$ is not sensibly defined in the way you say, imo. Formal constructions of $\Bbb C$ are easily available and in these $i$ has an entirely clear, unambiguous definition. "It just so happens" that $i^2=-1$ follows from these definitions. Moreover, it's worth noting that $i$ and $-i$ are algebraically indistinguishable; there is an automorphism of $\Bbb C$ as a field taking one to the other

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand. But my second question remains, how do we know there are only $2$ roots, without looking at $i$ as a number but as a "formal object"? Does the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra not rely on my definition of $i$?

Comment: @HappyDay: It is easy to check that over any field, a polynomial of degree $k$ has *at most* $k$ roots (counting multiplicity). So we know that $x^2+1$ has at most two roots in any field. All you need is the factor theorem.

Comment: Oh, got it. Lastly, how is $\Im$ defined? Because it seems to me that it is only well-defined if we assume that we are able to choose a root.

Comment: The imaginary part of a complex number is defined in terms of a specific representation of the complex numbers; you need to specify a root. You can define complex conjugation independent of the representation, which allows you to define the *real* part unambiguously (as $\frac{1}{2}(x+\overline{x})$), but the "imaginary part" depends on your choice of root, and is not an inherent function from the complex numbers to the real numbers.

Comment: That is, in fact $\Im$ is *not* well-defined until you specify what representation of $\mathbb{C}$ you want. If you want to identify them with the points in the real plane, so that $i$ is *defined* unambiguously as $(0,1)$, then there's not a problem (because that is your specific representaion of the complex numbers). If you want to define them by identifying them with the quotient $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$, then you need select one root $\alpha$, which allows you to express every complex number uniquely as $a+b\alpha$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and you use that representation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question! This is a subtle point that's easy to miss and points to a lot of rich mathematics.

> So, basically, there should be no way to distinguish the two (in the sense that replacing $i$ and $-i$ everywhere would yield the exact same results), right?

Yes, that's correct. This is a good example of [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory): precisely because there is, in some sense, no way to distinguish between $i$ and $-i$, [complex conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate), which swaps them, is a symmetry of the theory, and preserves true statements about complex numbers (although it would be a bit annoying to spell out exactly which statements, e.g. "the imaginary part is positive" is not preserved, but "this complex number is a root of this polynomial" is).

> But, operators such as $\Im$ (imaginary part) do let us distinguish between the two!
> How do we define the action of $\Im$ as well-defined?

We have to make a choice, and different ways of defining the complex numbers make the choice in different ways. If you define the complex numbers as the [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ then we simply decide that $x$, in this quotient ring, is the object we're going to call $i$ (even if we could also equally well have chosen $-x$). My preferred definition is to define the complex numbers as the subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ (the $2 \times 2$ real matrices) of matrices of the form

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & -b \\ b & a \end{array} \right].$$

Here the two square roots of $-1$ are the rotation matrices $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$, which perform a $90^{\circ}$ clockwise resp. counterclockwise rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can pick either one of these to be $i$ but the standard preferred choice is the second one, the counterclockwise rotation. So we see from this that choosing which square root of $-1$ to call $i$ amounts to choosing an [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability) of the plane.

Note that in the second definition, even without choosing which square root of $-1$ to call $i$, we can still define complex conjugation (it negates $b$) which means we can still write down the real part $\frac{z + \bar{z}}{2}$. We can write down the imaginary part in the sense that we can compute $\frac{z - \bar{z}}{2}$, but the result is not a real number but an element of a $1$-dimensional real vector space which we haven't chosen a basis of. Making a choice of $i$ fixes a basis of this vector space and then we can identify it with $\mathbb{R}$ by dividing by our choice of $i$.

> Secondly, does the definition assume that there are only $2$ complex roots to $x^2+1$?

No, you don't need to assume that, although it is true and follows from general facts about fields (if you believe that the complex numbers form a field).

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers all my questions.